# Configuring resource in Tomcat's context.xml to access remote JBoss queues

Tags: java, jboss, jms, tomcat8

Is it possible to access JBoss queues in tomcat by configuring JBoss properties in context.xml?

Below is the configuration i am using in context.xml file..

```
<Resource name="jmsconnectionfactory" auth="Container"
        type="javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory" description="JMS Connection Factory"
        factory="org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory" brokerURL="jnp://localhost:5432"/>
```

Exception observed is

```
Feb 14, 2018 1:09:24 PM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory.getObjectInstance(NamingContextFactory.java:83)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:94)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:847)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:158)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:835)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:158)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:835)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:172)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:157)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187)
```

Comment: Below is the configuration i am using in context.xml file..<Resource name="jndi.prod.engine" auth="Container"
  type="javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory" description="JMS Connection Factory"
  factory="org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory" brokerURL="jnp://localhost:5432"/>

Comment: What version of Jboss is it, e.g. EAP 4, 5, 6 or 7 or Wildfly version?

Comment: we are using Jboss 4